# Copy data from one column to another

Tags: column, data, copy

How to copy all data from one column which is type **Single line of text** and there are names in it to column **Created By** where the data is **Person or group** ?

There are over 1200 entries and I am looking for a way to automate it.

Comment: Is it for SharePoint Online or on-premise?

Comment: Also you can't overwrite the value of Created By as this is the user who uploaded the file, but you can create another field of the same data type (Person or Group) and copy it there.

Comment: Thomas , but how do I copy all the values to that new field (person or group) ? Whats the exact precedure?

Comment: Again it depends if you are using SharePoint Online or on-premise - which is it?

Comment: It is SharePoint Designer 2013 and also SharePoint Online

Comment: There's no real way to do it with a workflow, or rather there is BUT it's the triggering of the workflow thats the issue if you want it done against 1000+ items in one go to achieve a baseline. You'll be able to use a CSOM script to do it, I'll put something together and post shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create people & group field
2. Write a sharepoint designer workflow on edit item , to copy created by to newly created column. Publish workflow
3. Create new single line of text "Test"
4. Using datasheet view update the text in "Test' column. On updating the text in column, workflow will execute to set created by in new column.
5. Once all items are updated, delete the workflow and "Test" column.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but this way I have to manually execute the workflow for 1200+ items which is unthinkable

Comment: Workflwo has to on edit item. Using data sheet view it will be easy as u can drag drop the value in "Test" column, so will not take more than 2 mins. Create a view with 500 items and 2 columns like "Title" and "Test". That way it will be faster.

Comment: Another option is to write rest api method to update the items with test value to trigger the workflow.

Comment: @Lubos for my reference which method did you prefer ... update in datasheet view or REST API ?

Comment: update in datasheet

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to do the update - I ran this against a list where a field called 'personString' held the Text value, and 'personPerson' was the target for entering it as a 'proper' user identity.

Your machine will need the SharePoint Online Client Side Components, which you can download from MS (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42038), then you can run this in Powershell. CSOM via Powershell (and also via sp.js in the browser) is a really useful skill to learn, especially for SP Online.

Before running you obviously need to update my code with your own specific details for the logon, site address, field names etc but I've commented it pretty clearly.

```
#Import the required DLL
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")

# Set the site where the list lives and list name
$site = 'https://xxxx.sharepoint.com'
$listName = "PeopleTest"

# Set the user to run the query. Must be a Sharepoint Admin.
$admin = 'user@tenant'

# Set the password.
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "your password" -AsPlainText -Force

#Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)

#Authenticate
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($admin,$password)
$context.Credentials = $credentials

# Issue query to get the list, then execute it
$list = $context.web.lists.getbytitle($listName)
$context.load($list)
$context.executequery()

#echo $list.title

# Issue a CAML query and get all items
$query = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
$allItems = $list.GetItems($query)
$context.load($allItems)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

foreach ($item in $allItems) 
{ 
    # Find the user object based on the string value 
    $userLookup = $context.Web.EnsureUser($item["personString"]);  
    $context.Load($userLookup);  
    $context.ExecuteQuery();  

    # Build the username (for the Person field)
    $userName = $userLookup.Id.ToString() + ";#" + $userLookup.LoginName.ToString();  

    # Update the item
    $item["personPerson"] = $userName;  
    $item.Update();  
    $context.ExecuteQuery();  
}
```

Comment: For any new items going forward, just create a simple workflow that updates the field based on the existing value, and set it to run any time the item is edited... ideally though you should just be removing the String type column and force users to enter the value as a 'proper' user identity, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

afaik you must provide correct user id and login name to update a Person\Group field in sharepoint.

You can't just set "Mario" as field value or it will return a "read only" error.

the correct format to update a Person\group Field is "userId#;LoginName"
if you have this kind of information in the source column you can surely
update the Author or Created By fields with simple powershell script.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
[System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("SITEURL")
$web =  Get-SPWeb -Identity WEBURL
$list =$web.Lists["LISTNAME"]
$items = $list.items
foreach ($item in $items) 
{       
    //get or build the string in correct format from source column  
    //"100;#Mario" 
    $newAuthor = $item["SOURCECOLUMN"]

    $item["Author"] = $newAuthor 
    $item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
}   
$list.update()
```

Comment: Sound in theory but this will not work as it's Server Side OM and the target system is SharePoint Online.